# Is it possible to write a js variable into plain html?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, variables, dynamic

I am counting my user specificated and dynamically appearing divs...

My situation:

```
<div class="grid-stack" data-bind="foreach: {data: widgets, afterRender: afterAddWidget}">
<div id="streamcontainer1" class="streamcontainer grid-stack-item" data-bind="attr: {'data-gs-x': $data.x, 'data-gs-y': $data.y, 'data-gs-width': $data.width, 'data-gs-height': $data.height, 'data-gs-auto-position': $data.auto_position}">

</div>
</div>
```

In PHP i can simply write my COUNT variable inside the html. That would look something like this:

```
<div id="streamcontainer<?php echo $count ?>" class="" ... and so on...>
```

How can i archive the same with JS/Jquery?

Comment: PHP and JavaScript do two very different things.  PHP *generates* the HTML output (like you demonstrate).  JavaScript *uses* that resulting HTML output (which may involve modifying it in some way).  What are you trying to achieve with JavaScript?  What is the HTML that the JavaScript will be using, and what do you want to do with it?

Comment: what library or framework are you using that reads that `data-bind`? Is that knockout.js?

Comment: I dont know how that helps but hey, heres my backstory: I am using grid stack to create a user dashboard. In that dashboard the user has the option to stream different things in it like a youtube video or a simple facebook feed. Gridstack has a Template div(like a blueprint) that gets called everytime a user wants a new one. I need to number that things. so what iam trying to do is count all the existing one and add that number +1 to the new one.

Comment: @charlieetfl yep!

Comment: add that tag to question and give more specifics about what you need to accomplish

Comment: the point that annoys me a little bit is i can store the js variable in a php variable and throw it out but that cant be the right way to do this kind of things...

Comment: do what **specifically**? You have data arrays that can get counts from and knockout has rendering methods in their api that can manipulate any part of the dom

Comment: I try to be more specific: 
User has a few streamcontainers already open on his dashboard. 
Then he wants to have a Youtube video in the 5th streamcontainer.
So he pastes hes url in it and presses "go".
My script counts that clicked button and and gives the result back to my function that now knows that the users wants to see a youtube video and gets it from the YT Api.
But now my functions struggles -> it cant find "streamcontainer5" cause all are having the same ID

Comment: Again: Gridstack has these: <template id="gridstack-template"> things that are used by gs to know what they should display on the next click. So how am i going to add numbers to them? Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a DOM manipulation question. What do we have to work with? We're adding divs to the page, they have a particular class, and we want to give them an ID.

```
function assignIds(){
  var list = document.getElementsByClassName('streamcontainer');
  for(var i=0; i<list.length;i++){
    if(list[i].id == undefined) // skip the ones that have already been done.
      list[i].id = 'streamContainer' + i.toString();
  }
}
```

Now we just have to run that function on some event so it will keep updating. If you just want to do it on an interval, that's simplest. (`setInterval`) But that could give you a bug, where there's a small amount of time where that ID hasn't been assigned yet. You could try listening to whatever AJAX/websocket process is streaming these things onto the page.

We'd need to know a bit more about your use case to know which event to attach it to.

Comment: That is a great answer, sir! +1

Answer (score 0):

Without a Javascript Reactive Framework (Vue.js, React, AngularJS) you can't do this.
What you can do with JS is set a content in element when DOM is loaded, example:

```
document.getElementById("myElement").textContent = "Hello World!";
```

Or

```
document.getElementById("myElement").innerHTML = "<span>Hello World!</span>";
```

OBS: **.innerHTML** can insert HTML tags and **.textContent** just insert texts.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the `text` bindings in knockoutjs to display the javascript value in the HTML. There are lot of ko bindings which can help you. More reference [here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/text-binding.html)

```js
    var viewModel = {
        javascriptVariable: "I am javascript string"
    };
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<span data-bind="text: javascriptVariable"></span>
```